# Binomial coefficients products maximum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Is there anyone that can told me the solution to this problem?

Given two fixed non negative integers $n_1$ and $n_2$, and a non negative integer $k$, with $0  \le  k \le  \min(n_1,n_2)$.

For what value of $k$ is the following function maximal

$$h(k)=\binom{n_1}{k} \times \binom{n_2}{k}$$

Best Regards,
Davide

Answer (score 0):

We have $h(k+1)>h(k)$ if 
$$
{n_1\choose k+1}{n_2\choose k+1}>{n_1\choose k}{n_2\choose k}
$$
that is if
$$
{n_1!\over (k+1)!(n_1-k-1)!}{n_2!\over (k+1)!(n_2-k-1)!}>{n_1!\over k!(n_1-k)!}{n_2!\over k!(n_2-k)!}.
$$
This inequality can be rewritten as
$$
{(k!)^2(n_1-k)!(n_2-k)!\over \left((k+1)!\right)^2(n_1-k-1)!(n_2-k-1)!}>1
$$
and simplifying
$$
{(n_1-k)(n_2-k)\over (k+1)^2}>1.
$$
Then $h(k+1)>h(k)$ if 
$
(n_1-k)(n_2-k)>(k+1)^2$, that is if
$$k<{n_1n_2-1\over n_1+n_2+2}.$$
So the maximum is reached for the value immediately following that bound, that is for
$$
k=\left\lceil{n_1n_2-1\over n_1+n_2+2}\right\rceil.
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Is there any reference that you can give me to help me better understand this argument? Does the proof have a particular name so that I can search for it?

Comment: I don't think there is a particular name: it is just a pretty straightforward calculation. I've expanded a bit my answer in order to clarify the algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is pretty clear.